# Cómo comunicar una actividad con un fragmento

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría saber cómo acceder a las variables de una actividad desde su fragmento.

Pondré un ejemplo para aclarar mi duda:

Supongamos que tengo una actividad con una variable global llamada `ventanaFragmentoAbierta`, y quiero que cuando el fragmento abra uno de sus layouts ponga su valor a `true` y la actividad se entere en tiempo real (me gustaría trabajar en el `onBackPressed()` en función de esto).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la `Activity` defines tu método para modificar la variable:

```
public void setVariable(boolean valor){
   ventanaFragmentoAbierta = valor;
}
```

y lo accedes desde el `Fragment` de esta forma:

```
((TuActivity)getActivity()).setVariable(true);
```

---

Se realiza de esta forma ya que definir variable publica en una `Activity` puede dar lugar a problemas si tienes otra Activity con la misma variable publica, se debe asegurar acceder al método de la Clase para modificar su variable.

Comment: La forma correcta es implementar una interfaz para evitar dudas futuras cuando getActivity no tenga ese método (por claridad de código)

Comment: El Fragmento es cargado por la Activity en la cual se actualizaría la variable, una interfaz creo que es excesivo. La usaría si tuviera que actualizar una variable en una Activity diferente a la que carga el Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

**Define una interfaz**

En tu fragment defines una interfaz y haces que salte una excepción si el activity no la implementa

```
 // Tu Activity deberá implementar esta interfaz
public interface OnVarChangedFromFragment {
    public void onChangeVar();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // De esta forma te aseguras que la activity tenga la interfaz
    // Sino saltará una excepción
    try {
        mCallback = (OnVarChangedFromFragment) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " debes implementar OnVarChangedFromFragment");
    }
}
```

Cuando necesites notificar a tu activity llamas a la interfaz de tu fragmente de esta forma:

```
mCallback.onChangeVar();
```

Por otro lado tu activity implementará la interfaz

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements OnVarChangedFromFragment
```

Y cuando tu fragment llame al método haces lo que quieras en tu activity, la cual será notificada

Más info:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Implement

Comment: =0 Una interfaz para actualizar una variable? El fragmento es cargado por la Activity a la cual quiere actualizar una variable. Esto lo aplicaria para actualizar otra Activity diferente a la que carga el fragmento.

Comment: Una interfaz para comunicar una activity con todos los fragmentos a los que necesite comunicarse te parece raro, de verdad ?

Comment: Parece mentira que me des un negativo cuando he explicado la forma correcta de comunicar activity con fragment

Comment: No di negativo, y puede ser una forma, calro, pero no la usaria si tuviera varias variables que modificar con varias interfaces  =/

Answer (score -1):

Para acceder a una variable de una actividad desde un fragmento como lo llamas, te diría que está mal.
Quiero decir que lo que en verdad buscas es obtener una variable de una clase, para esto sólo debes de agregar `static` a la variable que quieras acceder desde otra clase por ejemplo..

```
public class Ejemplo {
public static int str_casa = -1;
```

tienes de inicializar ya que al llamar de otra clase va obtener el valor a no ser que haya sido alterada en el transcurso.
Ahora para llamar desde otra clase sólo tendrías que hacer esto..

```
Ejemplo.str_casa
```

y así obtendrías el valor que tiene dicha variable

Comment: Porque hay algo mal en acceder una variable de un _Activity_ desde un _Fragment_ (como Google lo llama)? El caso descrito en la pregunta probablemente es otro que piensas.

Comment: Esto no se debe hacer nunca, hay otras formas mas eficientes para la comunicación en java

Comment: Claro existen otras formas de llamar a los **contenidos** de otros `Views` pero pregunta dice bien claro que requiere obtener las variables de un fragmento, además que la persona editó su pregunta. Hubiera puesto que quería acceder a los `Views`.

Comment: @pcg26 hay pocas formas más eficientes en java que acceder un campo publico directamente, aun que hay muchas formas más estructurados, y sin duda no es la peor practica de usar _getters_ y _setters_. Supongo que te refieres a comunicación directa entre fragmentos con el "eso no se hace". Me gustaría saber porque no se debería acceder métodos de una _Activity_ directamente del _Fragment_. Si eso no se hace, no encuentro mucho sentido en el método _getActivity()_ de la clase _Fragment_..