# Cómo comunicar un Fragmento cargado con una Actividad

Tags: java, android

Supongamos que existe una `Activity` llamada Actividad y un `Fragment` llamado fragmento que tiene un método `pubic boolean setPantalla(boolean valor)`.

Me gustaría saber como ejecutar dicho método desde la actividad a través del método `onBackPressed()` (el fragmento ya ha sido previamente cargado y es el que está mostrado en la pantalla)

Lo que quiero decir es:
¿Cómo se ejecuta un método de un fragmento desde una actividad?

El caso contrario sería:

"En la Activity defines tu método para modificar la variable:

public void setVariable(boolean valor){
   ventanaFragmentoAbierta = valor;
}
y lo accedes desde el Fragment de esta forma:

((TuActivity)getActivity()).setVariable(true);" 
[Cómo comunicar una actividad con un fragmento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43985/c%C3%B3mo-comunicar-una-actividad-con-un-fragmento/44002#44002)

Busco algo que sea similar pero desde el punto de visto contrario.

Realmente lo que busco es la manera de acceder a una **variable** de un fragmento para así cambiarla desde la actividad

Comment: en el momento de crear tu fragment lo guardar en una variable del activity, y luego puedes acceder a los métodos públicos del fragment

Comment: ¿Podrías mandar un ejemplo? Realmente no lo entiendo muy bien.

Answer (score 1):

En tu activity:

```
    public class MiActivity extends Activity {

        private MiFragment miFragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           miFragment = MiFragment.newInstance();
           addFragment(miFragment); // todo: añade tu fragment con fragment manager
           miFragment.holaMundo();
        }

...
}
```

Tu fragment:

```
public class MiFragment extends Fragment {

    public static MiFragment newInstance() {
        return new MiFragment();
    }

    public void holaMundo(){
         ...
    }
```

Comment: Cuando dices añadir todo tu fragment te refieres a saltar al fragment? Yo parto del fragment inicializado (es lo mostrado en la pantalla). Tan sólo quiero acceder a un método del fragment ya mostrado a través del onBackPressed (actividad)

Comment: necesitas conseguir la instancia del fragment, en algún momento lo cargas, pues ahí lo guardas, y sino tienes que coger el fragment por su id